# Django lost session when I restart gunicorn

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django 1.6.2 final and using fabric with upstart on uBuntu.
The db (postgres) is on the same server.

When I restart the server I'm logged out from my web application.

Any ideas? What should I check?

Thanks

Comment: What's your session store? (Is it an in-memory store, because that'd do it!) Does your SECRET_KEY change?

Comment: I'm using the default used in django two scoops base template. I'm not changing any time the SECRET_KEY, this is my fab file: http://dpaste.com/1NB720P @KristianGlass

Comment: I'm using a subdomain and my django app is deployed on windows Azure servers (On a Linux VM)

Comment: Is there any chance that your session is naturally expiring due to a short set_expiry(value) and the server restart is not the real root cause?

Comment: Man i'v solved. My SECRET_KEY changed. Sorry and thanks.